# Как разбить строку на символы в Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разбить строку на символы в objective c?

Например, в массив, где каждый символ строки - отдельный элемента массива.

Comment: @maxprig, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы получить массив unichar'ов, используйте метод `NSString` `getCharacters:range:`

```
NSString* string = @"Hello";
NSUInteger length = [string length];
unichar buffer[length];
[string getCharacters:buffer range:NSMakeRange(0, length)];
```

Доступ по индексу:

```
unichar c = buffer[1]; // c равно 'e'
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще вариант, чтоб с С не связываться:

```
NSMutableArray *letterArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *letters = @"ABCDEFक्";
[letters enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [letters length]) 
                            options:(NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences) 
                         usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    [letterArray addObject:substring];
}];

for (NSString *i in letterArray){
    NSLog(@"%@",i);
}
```

[Источик, где еще варианты есть](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13839284/887325).