# Как введенное число разбить по элементам?

Tags: objective-c

У меня есть задание, ввести через терминал числа типа 57194063 после чего программа должны вывести числа в письменном виде пять семь один девять и тд, не важно с новой строки или последовательно. Если бы я брал с последнего элемента то способом остатка от деления делал, возможно было бы все проще. А как взять с первого числа последовательно не используя массив т.к. массив еще не проходил. Я думал возможно переменной объявить тип char и таким образом брать по одному символу и через условия прогонять, но как взять последовательно от первого число до n в зависимости сколько чисел ввели подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Если это учебное задание, то делайте сами. Если нет, сначала выучите язык.

Comment: Если делать вручную, вам придётся последовательным делением находить первую цифру, откусывать её, и повторять процесс, пока все цифры не будут выведены.

Comment: Так, для начала уточните: Пользователь вводит 5719063 в консоль. Ваша программа должна вывести в ту же консоль что-то типа 5 7 1 9 0 6 3 (или вариант когда не пробелы а с новой строки) так? (просто фраза "в письменном виде" не совсем понятна) И да, если с выводом проблем нет выше предложен вариант вполне идентичный упомянутому вами "способом остатка от деления"  только вы не остаток берёте а целую часть, и не с 0 цикл гоните, а от максимально возможного порядка. И не забываете вычитать пройденный порядок

Comment: Я должен вводить 58023 после чего нажимаю enter и мне выводится пять
восемь
ноль
два
три

Comment: Целую часть от деления мне начинать с какого делить?если ввести двухзначное число то делить на 10, сли трехзначное на 100 и тд., но если зараннее число не известно? Или я не правильно понял алгоритм?

Answer (score 1):

Предложу самый простой вариант:

- Перевести число в строку `NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",number]`;
- Циклично распарсить её.

Подобных задач воз и маленькая тележка в интернете. Как осуществить мой алгоритм Вы сможете найти без труда при помощи гугла.
Или если Вы живете в Китае где доступ к гуглу огрничен предоставляю Вам один из примеров: [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/388129/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-objective-c)

> Если делать вручную, вам придётся последовательным делением находить
> первую цифру, откусывать её, и повторять процесс, пока все цифры не
> будут выведены. – [VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd)

Данный вариант Вы тоже можете взять на размышление.